# How to parse "ものとも", when used at the end of a sentence in a Japanese dictionary entry?

Tags: grammar

Example:

[補説]「とも」は、引用の格助詞「と」に、係助詞「も」の付いたものとも。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to parse "ものとも", when used at the end of a sentence in a Japanese dictionary entry?

もの = noun
と = quotative particle
も = particle "also"

I'd understand it as the shortened form of ...ものとも言われる, literally "is also said to be something..."